# How to add html code to $newnode->setAttribute

Tags: php, dom, nodes, setattribute

How can i add some html code to a $newnode->setAttribute

This is the code of my node

```
$newnode->setAttribute("name",$row2['sitename']);
```

Now i want something like this

```
$newnode->setAttribute("name",<a href="link.php?id=$row2['id']">$row2['sitename']</a>);
```

Thanks for any help or links to sites where i can search for an solution

Comment: Why do you want to do this? I can't see the meaning of a href inside a name attribute. Additionally this would produce invalid html

Comment: I have a dinamic google map with multiple markers and info window. I want now when the user clicks on the marker they can click on name. Them comes a new site with details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the help.

I have now the solution and here is it complete

xml.php

```
    // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE
  $node = $dom->createElement("marker");
  $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
  $newnode->setAttribute("name",$row2['sitename']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("address", $row['formatted_adress']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['longi']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("id", $row2['id']);
}
```

javascript google maps code

```
downloadUrl("xml.php", function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
      var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
      var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
      var site_id = markers[i].getAttribute("id");
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
      var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address + " <br/> <a href='index.php?id=" + site_id +"'>more...</a><br />";
      var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        icon: icon.icon
      });
      bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The 'name' attribute is used for form controls (e.g. an input element), but it looks like you want to actually create a link element instead. Here's an example of that, where $doc is your document object:

```
$newNode = $doc->createElement("a",$row2['sitename']);
$newNode->setAttribute("href","link.php?id=".$row2['id']);
```

Once appended to your DOM tree, the expected output of the element would be something like:

```
<a href="link.php?id=123">yoursitename</a>
```